How to fix " package javafx.embed.swing does not exist" error with JavaFX in JGrasp IDE?
I downloaded the JavaFX SDK from https://gluonhq.com/. I moved it to my Java folder, I've changed the environment variables to point to the bin folder there. I've tried changing the CLASSPATH in JGrasp, too. How do I get JavaFX to work? The following is the error I'm receiving.
NumSlider.java:11: error: package javafx.embed.swing does not exist
import javafx.embed.swing.*;
^


Unless your program really requires javafx.embed.swing, why not import javafx.scene.control.Slider? Please [edit] your question to elaborate and include a [mre] that illustrates the problem you describe.

I'm not sure if JGrasp supports Maven and/or Gradle, but those two build systems are probably the easiest way to generate JavaFX projects, managing dependencies along the way

It's the same error message. I can't get JGrasp to recognize JavaFX @trashgod

"I downloaded the JavaFX SDK from https://gluonhq.com/. I moved it to my Java folder, I've changed the environment variables to point to the bin folder there ...  I've tried changing the CLASSPATH" -> that is not how the SDK is designed to be used.  Read the openjfx getting started documentation for intended usage instructions.

"It's the same error message." -> it can't be.  If you import javafx.scene.control.Slider instead of javafx.embed.swing.*, you will not generate an error message: package javafx.embed.swing does not exist for an import statement that does not exist.

@jewelsea I tried following the directions there. It's all about running JavaFX java files from the command line, and using JavaFX with IIntelliJ, Netbeans, Eclipse, Visual Studio, Gradle, and Maven. I don't have any of that. That's why I specified how do I get it to work on JGrasp. I think you took me too literally. I meant the same message package whatever.package.im.talking.about does not exist. It just isn't recognizing JavaFX.

You are unlikely to get a specific answer on the use of JavaFX on JGrasp.  You will probably need to apply what you learned from studying the resources provided and adapt that for use in your chosen environment.

For JavaFX to work, all of these need to be true -> 1. Required JavaFX modules are on the module path (java and javac) 2. Required JavaFX modules are added to the module graph via either a module-info requirement or an --add-modules VM parameter (java and javac) 3. JavaFX native libraries for your architecture can be loaded by the JVM, either by using the JavaFX maven modules or the native libraries provided with the SDK. 4. You need to be developing and running using an appropriate JDK and runtime (e.g. Java 17+ for JavaFX 21+).

"I don't have any of that." -> You must have a JDK (which has java and javac) command as you cannot develop JavaFX without one.  I have never used JGrasp, but it must interface with both java and javac in some way to allow development to occur, in which case you need to provide the appropriate inputs to those commands to allow JavaFX to be recognized (probably using some configuration dialog box in your chosen IDE).

One thing you could try is to use a JDK which already includes JavaFX, rather than adding the JavaFX modules via dependencies, module info or command line switches.  You could use Azul "JDK FX" or Liberica "Full JDK" - make sure you choose the appropriate version "JDK FX" or "Full JDK" and not other versions that do not include JavaFX.

JavaFX settings in jGRASP are at "Settings" -> "Compiler Settings" -> "Workspace" (or your project) -> "JavaFX" tab. You can specify the JavaFX location and additional modules there (only javafx.controls is there by default). You can use the "Flags/Args" tab if you need flags other than just modules.
